# FGSM attack in Foolbox

Tags: pytorch, adversarial-attack

I am using Foolbox 3.3.1 to perform some adversarial attacks on resnet50 network. The code is as follows:

```
import torch
from torchvision import models

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True).to(device)
model.eval()

mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
preprocessing = dict(mean=mean, std=std, axis=-3)
bounds = (0, 1)
fmodel = fb.models.PyTorchModel(model, bounds=bounds, preprocessing=preprocessing)

images, labels = fb.utils.samples(fmodel, dataset='imagenet', batchsize=8)
labels_float = labels.to(torch.float32)


def perform_attack(attack, fmodel, images, labels, predicted_labels_before_attack):
    print(f'Performing attack with {type(attack).__name__}...', end='')
    raw, clipped, is_adv = attack(fmodel, images, labels, epsilons=0.03)
    print('done')
    logits_after_attacks = fmodel(clipped)
    labels_after_attack = logits_after_attacks.max(dim=1)[1].cpu().numpy()
    for image, predicted_label_before_attack, label, label_after_attack in zip(images, predicted_labels_before_attack, labels.cpu().numpy(), labels_after_attack):
        label_imshow = type(attack).__name__
        if predicted_label_before_attack == label and label != label_after_attack:
            label_imshow += '; successful attack'
        label_imshow += f'\nTrue class: {lab_dict[label]}\nClassified before attack as: {lab_dict[predicted_label_before_attack]}\nClassified after attack as: {lab_dict[label_after_attack]}'
        imshow(image, label_imshow)
        
for attack in (
                fb.attacks.FGSM(), # "nll_loss_forward_no_reduce_cuda_kernel_index" not implemented for 'Int'
              ):
    perform_attack(attack, fmodel, images, labels, predicted_labels_before_attack)
```

I get the error:

> RuntimeError: "nll_loss_forward_no_reduce_cuda_kernel_index" not implemented for 'Int'

with full stack:

```
        Performing attack with LinfFastGradientAttack...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1736/3238714708.py in <module>
     28 #                 fb.attacks.BoundaryAttack(),  # very slow
     29               ):
---> 30     perform_attack(attack, fmodel, images, labels, predicted_labels_before_attack)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1736/3978727835.py in perform_attack(attack, fmodel, images, labels, predicted_labels_before_attack)
      1 def perform_attack(attack, fmodel, images, labels, predicted_labels_before_attack):
      2     print(f'Performing attack with {type(attack).__name__}...', end='')
----> 3     raw, clipped, is_adv = attack(fmodel, images, labels, epsilons=0.03)
      4     print('done')
      5     logits_after_attacks = fmodel(clipped)

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\foolbox\attacks\base.py in __call__(***failed resolving arguments***)
    277         success = []
    278         for epsilon in real_epsilons:
--> 279             xp = self.run(model, x, criterion, epsilon=epsilon, **kwargs)
    280 
    281             # clip to epsilon because we don't really know what the attack returns;

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\foolbox\attacks\fast_gradient_method.py in run(self, model, inputs, criterion, epsilon, **kwargs)
     90             raise ValueError("unsupported criterion")
     91 
---> 92         return super().run(
     93             model=model, inputs=inputs, criterion=criterion, epsilon=epsilon, **kwargs
     94         )

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\foolbox\attacks\gradient_descent_base.py in run(***failed resolving arguments***)
     90 
     91         for _ in range(self.steps):
---> 92             _, gradients = self.value_and_grad(loss_fn, x)
     93             gradients = self.normalize(gradients, x=x, bounds=model.bounds)
     94             x = x + gradient_step_sign * stepsize * gradients

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\foolbox\attacks\gradient_descent_base.py in value_and_grad(self, loss_fn, x)
     50         x: ep.Tensor,
     51     ) -> Tuple[ep.Tensor, ep.Tensor]:
---> 52         return ep.value_and_grad(loss_fn, x)
     53 
     54     def run(

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\eagerpy\framework.py in value_and_grad(f, t, *args, **kwargs)
    350     f: Callable[..., TensorType], t: TensorType, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
    351 ) -> Tuple[TensorType, TensorType]:
--> 352     return t.value_and_grad(f, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354 

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\eagerpy\tensor\tensor.py in value_and_grad(self, f, *args, **kwargs)
    541         self: TensorType, f: Callable[..., TensorType], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
    542     ) -> Tuple[TensorType, TensorType]:
--> 543         return self._value_and_grad_fn(f, has_aux=False)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    544 
    545     @final

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\eagerpy\tensor\pytorch.py in value_and_grad(x, *args, **kwargs)
    493                 loss, aux = f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    494             else:
--> 495                 loss = f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    496             loss = loss.raw
    497             loss.backward()

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\foolbox\attacks\gradient_descent_base.py in loss_fn(inputs)
     40         def loss_fn(inputs: ep.Tensor) -> ep.Tensor:
     41             logits = model(inputs)
---> 42             return ep.crossentropy(logits, labels).sum()
     43 
     44         return loss_fn

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\eagerpy\framework.py in crossentropy(logits, labels)
    319 
    320 def crossentropy(logits: TensorType, labels: TensorType) -> TensorType:
--> 321     return logits.crossentropy(labels)
    322 
    323 

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\eagerpy\tensor\pytorch.py in crossentropy(self, labels)
    462             raise ValueError("labels must be 1D and must match the length of logits")
    463         return type(self)(
--> 464             torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(self.raw, labels.raw, reduction="none")
    465         )
    466 

~\anaconda3\envs\adversarial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

RuntimeError: "nll_loss_forward_no_reduce_cuda_kernel_index" not implemented for 'Int'
```

Any clue?

Comment: Your perform_attack function has an argument `predicted_labels_before_attack` I do not find this variable in your code?

Comment: Also try to see the values of images whether it is float of integer.

Comment: I corsssposted it to https://github.com/bethgelab/foolbox/issues/666. It was a bug, see workaround there.

Comment: You only installed the last version and it worked!

Comment: Version 3.3.2 is published on pypi, it seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is on the 3978727835.py file try to change the argument labels to 'labels.to(DEVICE).long()' if you use CUDA unless change it to 'labels.long()'

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @samson wmariam.